# Why doesn't variables take value from manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

I am new to *Mathematica* and I am working on a code on which the final output depends on variables evaluated from the inputs
A simplified example: (x,y) inputs ,(q,w) intermediate values, (z) output

```
x = Input["x"]
y = Input["y"]
q = 2 x
w = 3 y
z = 4 q + 5 w
f = 3 x + 4 y
```

This works just fine, but I want to manipulate the inputs so i tried

```
q = 2 x
w = 3 y
Manipulate[z = 4 q + 5 w, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

the result for z is `8x+15y` that doesn't change with moving x and y sliders.. so i tried

```
Manipulate[q = 2 x, {x, 0, 10}]
Manipulate[w = 3 y, {y, 0, 10}]
z = 4 q + 5 w
f = 3 x + 4 y
```

which worked for z but did not work for f as apparently the values of x and y aren't stored
my questions are
1- how to set the values for x and y from manipulate ?
2- the value of z isn't evaluated when i move the sliders but i have to run the code again and the sliders are thus reset. How can i get the result of z instantaneously by moving the sliders of x and y.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach slightly different from LLIAMnYP's answer to is to go ahead and treat the **x** and **y** variables as local to Manipulate. In this approach **x** and **y** are updated dynamically and used to compute the intermediate results, **q** and **w**.

**x** and **y** are used to directly compute **f** but the intermediate results are used to compute **z**.

One uses DyanmicModule to localize **q**, **w**, **f** and **z**.

```
Manipulate[

 DynamicModule[
  {
   q = 2 x,
   w = 3 y,
   f,
   z
   },

  f = 3 x + 4 y;
  z = 4 q + 5 w;

  Row[{"f = ", f, "  z = ", z}]
  ], (* end of DynamicModule *)

 {{x, 1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{y, 2}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

Row is used to display the results. Below is what it looks like for the initial settings x=1 and y=2.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is scoping. `x` and `y` inside the `Manipulate` are not the same `x` and `y` that you use globally. In order to remedy this, use the option `LocalizeVariables -> False`.

```
Manipulate[{q = 2 x, w = 3 y}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, LocalizeVariables -> False]
(* slide around *)
x
(* 3.74 *)
z = 4 q + 5 w
f = 3 x + 4 y
(* 103.72 *)
(* 30.9 *)
```

Perhaps a further improvement, try

```
Dynamic[z = 4 q + 5 w]
Dynamic[f = 3 x + 4 y]
```

and watch the values of `f` and `z` be updated on-the-fly.